# ASP.NET trigger CallbackPanel callback from javascript every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, callback

Im trying to trigger callback of CallbackPanel with javascript in my WebFormUserControl every 10 seconds.

Im able to trigger it with ASPxButton and ClientSideEvents, but my goal is to start it automatically every 10 seconds.
My UserControl code:

```
<dxcb:ASPxCallbackPanel ID="panel" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="panel" OnCallback="ASPxCallbackPanel1_Callback" Width="200px">
            <PanelCollection>
                <dxcb:PanelContent runat="server">
                    <dxcb:ASPxImage ID="ASPxImage1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Image1.png" ShowLoadingImage="true"></dxcb:ASPxImage>
                </dxcb:PanelContent>
            </PanelCollection>
</dxcb:ASPxCallbackPanel>
 <dxcb:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Text="ASPxButton">
            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) { panel.PerformCallback();  }" />
 </dxcb:ASPxButton>
```

I tried to fire it ever 10 seconds like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
setInterval(function () { panel.PerformCallback(); }, 10000);
</script>
```

Is is possible to achieve my goal? 
If so, please provide some useful code.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `__doPostBack` while passing the id of your CallBackPanel. Like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    setInterval(function () {
        __doPostBack("<%= panel.ClientID %>", "PanelCalledBack");
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

Then check against your passed `PanelCalledBack` argument in your panel's `OnLoad` event (if it has one) or in the `Page_Load` event:

```
if (Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT")?.Trim().IndexOf("PanelCalledBack") != -1)
{
    ASPxCallbackPanel1_Callback(panel, null);
}
```

Comment: But it will refresh entire page, doesnt it?
My goal is to refresh only ASPxImage control.

Comment: No it will not since you're passing the control id

Comment: That's how the standard UpdatePanel works. You'll have to test it against your control.